# How to display custom attribute (option) in onepage checkout "order review" block and order confirmation email?

Tags: email, magento, attributes, checkout

Is it possible to display custom option like 'color' for instance in the order review during checkout? Same question about confirmation email. 
I've looked at the template for the cart item renderer and there is a foreach loop over the product options... But how do i put a custom option in there?

At the moment i just load the product again and manually pull out the attribute in the template... But it is 
a) not portable
b) has to be done in all of the templates where i want to display custom option

Is there a correct way of doing this?

Comment: take a look at cart items renderer where this is displayed and merge

Comment: How is the product set up?
1. Simple product w/ config options

or

2. Configurable product

Answer (score 2):

The product doesn't contain all of the attributes. Instead of the load attributes by new query, you can define in config.xml file what attributes you want to load during the checkout like below :

```
<sales>
  <quote>
    <item>
      <product_attributes>
        <attribute_1 />
        <attribute_2 />
      </product_attributes>
    </item>
  </quote>
</sales>
```